# Fs2 Stream.Compiler is not found (could not find implicit value Compiler[[x]F[x],G])

Tags: scala, fs2

I am trying to compile the stream, but somehow `Compiler` is not in scope, what context bound is needed for bringing it in scope?

```
import cats.Monad

def compilingStream[F[_]: Monad]: F[List[Int]] = {
  val stream: fs2.Stream[F, Int] = fs2.Stream.emit(1).covary[F]
  stream.head.compile.toList
}


error: could not find implicit value for parameter compiler: fs2.Stream.Compiler[[x]F[x],G]
         stream.head.compile.toList
                     ^
```

Answer (score 7):

Fs2 `Stream#compile` now requires a `Sync[F]` (see [this](https://twitter.com/djspiewak/status/1004128360740470784)):

```scala
  import cats.effect.Sync

  def compilingStream[F[_]: Sync]: F[List[Int]] = {
    val stream: fs2.Stream[F, Int] = fs2.Stream.emit(1).covary[F]
    stream.head.compile.toList
  }
```

This is communicated by the library maintainer:

> fs2 Stream#compile now requires a Sync[F]. Even on completely pure streams. Because of resource management. Sad. Panda.
>
> Daniel Spiewak

Comment: I see, I though it was required, but I couldn't find a online resource to confirm it! I'll update the answer accordingly! Thanks