# fs2 Stream scala No implicit of type : Stream.Compiler[Eval,G_]

Tags: scala, eval, scala-cats, fs2

I'm trying to create a Stream[Eval, String] as follows :

```
import cats.Eval
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import fs2._

object StringEval extends IOApp {

  def evalString: Eval[String] = Eval.always{
      val r = new scala.util.Random(31)
      r.nextString(4)
    }

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {

    Stream
      .eval(evalString)
      .repeat
      .compile
      .lastOrError
      .start
      .as(ExitCode.Success)

  }
}
```

But the problem is that I'm getting a compilation error saying :

```
Error:(17, 8) could not find implicit value for parameter compiler: fs2.Stream.Compiler[[x]cats.Eval[x],G]
      .compile
```

I can't seem to get the error ? what am I missing? What does the error refer to ?

Comment: i think that you should avoid using `Eval` datatype to capture side-effects, due to not having handling errors capabilities (there's no instance of `MonadError[Eval]`). Maybe `Sync` datatype is good a choice for your problem.

Comment: That was just for testing, IO does the thing so there is no problem with  the way the program is organized ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fs2 Stream.Compiler is not found (could not find implicit value Compiler[[x]F[x],G])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329032/fs2-stream-compiler-is-not-found-could-not-find-implicit-value-compilerxfx)

> Fs2 `Stream#compile` now requires a `Sync[F]`

`Eval` doesn't have instance of `Sync`, `IO` does.

Try

```
def evalString: IO[String] = {
  val r = new scala.util.Random(31)
  Sync[IO].delay(r.nextString(4))
}

Stream
  .eval(evalString)
  .repeat
  .compile
  .lastOrError
  .start
  .as(ExitCode.Success)
```

Comment: I've tried the example with IO and it is working perfectly, the thing is that I'm trying to understand why it is not working with Eval, it seems that it requires an instance of Sync , but why ? I don't get it

Comment: @MunaAr Have you read the link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329032/fs2-stream-compiler-is-not-found-could-not-find-implicit-value-compilerxfx https://twitter.com/djspiewak/status/1004128360740470784

Comment: I did I'm new to all of this sorry